# Indirect object pronoun questions

Tags: objetos-indirectos

I am making my way through Spanish grammar and still a bit hung up on pronouns, especially with indirect objects. 
Question:
For example, this sentence: I write an e-mail to him.
Do I have these parts right?
Subject = I
Verb = write
Direct object = e-mail
Indirect object = him

So, in Spanish it would be:
Le escribo un email. (or)  Le escribo un email a él.

Part of the book states the following about Indirect object pronouns:
*Indirect object nouns or pronouns refer only to people (and to
beloved pets); they answer the question “To or for whom is
the subject doing something?” An indirect object pronoun can
replace an indirect object noun **but also is used in Spanish
when the indirect object noun is mentioned**.*

Another question
Do I understand it correctly that **IF** a sentence has an indirect object that is a person/pet, then it's always correct to use the pronoun for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I write an e-mail to him.**

Yo escribo un e-mail a él - Yo le escribo un e-mail.

---

- El Complemento indirecto indica la persona o cosa a quien va destinada la acción verbal; suele ir precedido de la preposición **a**. "Blanca compró un libro **a sus abuelos**"

> The indirect object indicates the person or thing to whom the verbal
> action is intended; It is usually preceded by the preposition **a**.
> "Blanca compró un libro **a sus abuelos**"

- **El Objeto Indirecto admite la duplicación** con los pronombres átonos (los pronombres personales átonos son aquellos que funcionan como complemento **directo o indirecto** ) me, te, se, lo, los, le, les, la, las, nos, os, en la misma oración.

> **The Indirect Object supports duplication** with unstressed pronouns
> (unstressed personal pronouns are those that function as a **direct or
> indirect** complement) me, te, se, lo, los, le, les, la, las, nos ,
> os, in the same sentence.

**Importante** / Important

- Los pronombres que sustituyen al **objeto directo** son:
  me, te, lo, la, nos, os, los, las.

> The pronouns that replace the **direct object** are;
> me, te, lo, la, nos, os, los, las.

- Los que sustituyen al **objeto indirecto** son: me, te, le, nos, os, les.

> Those that replace the **indirect object** are:  me, te, le, nos, os, les.

---

**El Objeto Indirecto admite la duplicación** / Indirect Object supports duplication

Yo escribí un e-mail a mi hermano.

**A mi hermano** **le** escribí un e-mail - (A mi hermano escribí un e- mail)

---

- **Le** escribí un e-mail **a mi hermano** - (Escribí un e-mail **a mi hermano**).
- **Le** escribí un libro **a mi hermano** - (Escribí un libro **a mi hermano**).
- **Le** compré un libro **a mi hermana** - (Compré un libro **a mi hermana**).
- **A ti te** duele la pierna - (**Te** duele la pierna).
- **A mí me** gusta mucho el deporte - (**Me** gusta mucho el deporte).